# How do I reduce the loglevel on rippled?

Tags: ripple, ripple-api

By default, rippled seems to log at the NFO level, which spits out many megabytes of log files each day. How do I reduce this level? According to the [Ripple wiki](https://ripple.com/wiki/Rippled_Troubleshooting#Logging_Severity), we can edit pass arguments to rippled when starting it, or edit the configuration file via [rpc_startup], but neither of these methods had any effect for me (on v0.23.0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the following in your `rippled.cfg` file:

```
[rpc_startup]
{ "command" : "log_level", "severity" : "error" }
```

Comment: Thanks! I see that the wiki was updated with the correct severities.